# Using drupal_static var across modules

Tags: php, drupal, static, drupal-7, global-variables

I want to set a global variable that any module in my Drupal project can see and get its value. Here is my code :

- My module 1 :

  ```
  function setGlobalDocId($params){
      $global_selected_DocId = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__);
      $global_selected_DocId=$params;
  }
  ```
- My module 2 :

  ```
  $selectedId=&drupal_static('setGlobalDocId');
    echo (" selectedId  = ".$selectedId);
  ```

I am pretty sure that `setGlobalDocId()` in my module 1 was executed before the call to the global variable in my module 2. Did I miss something? I had nothing as output.

Comment: I fixed the formatting; you need a total of 8 leading spaces to put code under a bullet point. Also, I changed the title to be a bit more specific. I don't know Drupal, but it seems like there isn't enough context to answer the question yet. Maybe you could add a minimal example of how you are executing those modules?

Comment: thank you @JonEricson, in fact my static variable have to be set by the first module and I need to get its value via the second. T thought `drupal_static` will solve the problem but it didn't work I don't know why, I gave a try for a `cache` variable but I think it's not optimal since my variable has a sensitive data , so I decided to merge the two modules into one to avoid the communication issue, it's temporary solution but it's fine until now, thank you any way and I'am sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

In your code example, you are creating`$global_selected_DocId` in `setGlobalDocId` as a global variable. But in your `module 2`, instead of requesting the global `$global_selected_DocId`, you are requesting a variable with the name `setGlobalDocId` which doesn't exist in your case.

To resolve this, you should use the same code structure in `module 2` as in `module 1`.

```
$global_selected_DocId = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, null);
if ($global_selected_DocId === null) {
    //global_selected_DocId is not set, do a fallback or someting else to capture exception
}

//global_selected_DocId should contain value set through setGlobalDocId in module 1
```

Comment: no same result !!, any way I used cache_set() and it is fine, thanks for your time Mike.

Comment: Strange ... you are sure that `setGlobalDocId` is called before module 2 and on the same page request ?

Comment: yes, I merged the two modules as a temporary solution better than cache variable.